# Relaxation/thermalization of High spin nuclei

Tags: thermodynamics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

Is it practical to keep nuclei excited to high spin for long(ish) times?

What mechanisms drive the relaxation of nuclear spin?

Which texts would treat this subject with detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What mechanisms drive the relaxation of nuclear spin?

Excited states of nuclei are unstable with respect to gamma decay.

On a plot of excitation energy versus spin, there is a line called the yrast line (meaning "dizziest" in Swedish, IIRC), which the the set of states of minimum energy for a fixed spin. States high above the yrast line have very short half-lives, because there is a high density of states for them to decay to. If you're looking for long-lived high-spin states, you want to look for yrast states.

A common mechanism for a high-spin state to be long lived is that it's an yrast trap. In such a situation, the yrast line is not monotonic. It has a big jump downward. Then you have a state that can't decay without emitting a photon with a large angular momentum, which tends to have a long half-life.

We can also have yrast states that have long half-lives because of the approximate conservation of the K quantum number. These are called K isomers. In a nucleus that has a prolate deformation, the projection K of the angular momentum along the axis of symmetry, in the body-fixed frame, is nearly conserved. (Conservation is violated because the Coriolis force mixes K values, and also because the nucleus has zero-point motion about the symmetric shape.)

The most celebrated example is a state in 178Hf with a half-life of 31 years and spin 16. There have been proposals to produce this state in macroscopic quantities and to use it in making gamma-ray lasers.

> Which texts would treat this subject with detail?

AFAIK high-spin isomers are not a standard textbook subject.